# bypass attr_accessible/protected in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model that, when it instantiates an object, also creates another object with the same user id.

```
class Foo > ActiveRecord::Base

after_create: create_bar

private

def create_bar
  Bar.create(:user_id => user_id #and other attributes)
end

end
```

In Bar.rb I have attr_protected to protect it from hackers.

```
class Bar > ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :user_id, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```

As it stands now I can't seem to create a new Bar object without either disabling the attr_protected or having the Bar object's user_id go blank...

How can I let the bar object accept the :user_id attribute from foo without losing protection from attr_protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
def create_bar
  bar = Bar.build(... other params ...)
  bar.user_id = user_id
  bar.save!
end
```

Comment: This works! Thanks jonnii.
except that in my case I did bar = user.bar.build(...parameters)

Answer (score 10):

When calling `new`, `create`, or `find_or_create_by` (and any others that end up calling `new`) you can pass an additional option, `without_protection: true`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.22/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-new

Answer (score 2):

`attr_protected` filters the attributes in the `attributes=` method wich is called in `new`. You can solve your problem with:

```
def create_bar
  Bar.new( other attributes ) do |bar|
    bar.user_id = user_id
    bar.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah! I see, as long as you get out of new, it works. That's why the other answer worked for me too.

Comment: This version returns the object as in your example, not true/false.